# Discord.py send the author of a message information about how many people reacted with a certain reaction

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm designing a Discord bot that can basically be used throughout your server for different useful tasks, like getting server statistics, DMing a user, and (the topic of this question) making a poll. The code I have is pretty long, so I'm only going to include the imports, important variables, actual code where I'm having a problem, and the end where I run my bot:

```
from profanity import profanity
import os, random, discord, asyncio, praw

from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
intents = discord.Intents().all()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!", case_insensitive=True, intents=intents)
devmode = False

@bot.command(name='makePoll', help="Makes a new poll that other users can vote for. Bob Bot may be erroring out because it does not have the highest permissions in the server, so you will need to give it roles to kick users.")
async def makeapoll(ctx,*, message : str):
  embed=discord.Embed(title=random.choice(pollNames), description=message, color=0xfcd602)
  embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name + " (you can end this poll by reacting with this: )", url=random.choice(aintsupposedtobeheresunnyboy), icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
  mymsg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
  await mymsg.add_reaction('✅')
  await mymsg.add_reaction('❌')

  def check(reaction, user):
    return user == ctx.message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''
  try:
    reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    await ctx.send("Some kind of error occured. Sowwy.")

  

  deletionEmbed = discord.Embed(title="This ends now!", value="It's over, Anakin... I have the high ground", color=0xfcd602)
  deletionEmbed.add_field(name="The poll ended!", value=f"The poll's author {ctx.author.display_name} just declared that the poll ended. RIP poll :(\n\nFor those of you who missed the question, here it is: *{message}*\n\n{ctx.author.display_name}, the results of the poll should have been DMed to you right about now. Happy statistical advancement!", inline=False)

  await mymsg.edit(embed=deletionEmbed)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Basically, what I want to do here is that when the author of a poll reacts with a red dot  (which is used to officially stop the poll), my bot direct-messages the author of the poll with the most recent information about who reacted with any reaction. For example, if two people reacted with a checkmark and three people with a cross, I want the bot to message the poll's author with those stats: 2 checks and 3 crosses. If another user responded with a check after the poll, I don't want to reflect those changes. I tried using the add_raw_reaction function, but that didn't seem to work either. How could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the poll stats and send a DM with those numbers after your `wait_for` completes (when the author reacts or it times out). To do this, you first need to re-fetch the message so that you can obtain the updated reaction data since the original `Message` object does not update by itself.

```py
mymsg = await mymsg.channel.fetch_message(mymsg.id)
```

Afterwards, you can get the [`Reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#reaction) objects from the message and compile a dictionary mapping the emojis to their count. Instead of just iterating through [`Message.reactions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.reactions) since it could include extraneous emojis, it's a good idea to have a list of just the emoji that's part of the poll, ✅ and ❌, and then only get the reactions for those using `discord.utils.get`.

```py
choices = ['✅', '❌']
counts = {}
for emoji in choices:
    reaction = discord.utils.get(mymsg.reactions, emoji=emoji)
    counts[emoji] = reaction.count - 1  # minus 1 to exclude the bot
```

Now with the numbers stored in `count`, you can choose however you want to format your stats and then call `.send()` on the author to send the DM.

```py
results = ...
await ctx.author.send(results)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @thegamecracks, that worked absolutely perfectly! I'll make sure to credit you in my program :)